# How to initialise a std_logic to '0' in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to build a Matrix Vector Multiplier in VHDL using structural modelling.

I want to initialise a std_logic to '0' but when I run the simulation, it is getting initialised to 'U' which is causing the output of the D Flip Flop connected to it to remain 'U', which is also a std_logic.

How do I initialise the std_logic to '0' without using reset using any if-else statement like

```
if reset = '1' then
Zindata <= '0'
end if;
```

I am getting error when I am using the above piece of code, when I am doing structural modelling.

Is there any way to initialise `Zindata` to '0' without doing like in the above code?

Comment: You if statement doesn't provide a [mcve] and doesn't allow identifiying either your original problem or the issue with your [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) solution.  Identifying drivers and examining declarations can be essential for determining simulation problems in VHDL.

Comment: WRT the answer below, why can't you just reset the flip-flop(s)? That would be a better solution than initialising a signal in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the signal an initial value when you declare it:

```
signal Zindata : std_logic := '0';
```

If you don't explicitly give it an initial value, it will get the leftmost value in the type declaration. That's why your signal has the value 'U'.

From [std_logic_1164.vhd](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/packages/std_logic_1164.vhd), the definition of std_ulogic (std_logic is the resolved type of std_ulogic):

```
TYPE std_ulogic IS ( 'U',  -- Uninitialized
                     'X',  -- Forcing  Unknown
                     '0',  -- Forcing  0
                     '1',  -- Forcing  1
                     'Z',  -- High Impedance   
                     'W',  -- Weak     Unknown
                     'L',  -- Weak     0       
                     'H',  -- Weak     1       
                     '-'   -- Don't care
                   );
```

Comment: Correct, but be careful if you want to do synthesis. Not all target technologies support initial values.